# Firebase handle Email verification

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, email-verification

i'm trying to verify a Firebase account in my application.

I included the functon for sending the verification mail and after the person clicked the link in the mail, his verification status in Firebase is true.

My problem is now that i cant receive the change in my ionic 2 application.
For example i tried to get the verfication state in the onAuthStateChange Method from firebase and write it to my Database with the updateUser function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
  this.zone.run( () => {
    if (!user) { 
      this.rootPage = Login; 
    } else {
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
      auth.setUser(user);

      if(user.emailVerified){
        this.auth.updateUser({verified: true});
      }
    }
  });     
});
```

When i register a user the emailVerified is false, after i click on the link, logout from the app and log in again the status is true, so everythink should be okay.
Now my question is, if i can handle the change of the emailVerified "on the fly" so that the user dont have to relog, like an eventlistener or something who is called when the emailVerified status in firebase is changed.

Would be nice if someone have a idea or a tipp for me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the user profile:

```
user.reload().then(...
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload

Comment: Yeah but the Problem is that funktion should be called when the user clicks in the Link in the Mail and the emailVerified value is set.

Comment: Like the firebase.database.ref.on (value) function who is called everytime something is changed